# OpenCV Nomalize on distance map

Tags: opencv, image-processing, normalization

I was wondering does anyone know / where I could find the calculations or formulas used for OpenCV's Normalize function on a distance map given the beta value 0 and alpha value 1, with the normalization type NORM_MINMAX:

normalize(distanceT, distanceT, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX);

I cannot find any information in the documentation so I have been looking at articles such as:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_%28image_processing%29

but doing the calculations do not yield the same results as the OpenCV's algorithm.

Many thanks.

Comment: Your question is too vague!

Comment: I don't understand how my question is at all vague - I was wondering does anyone know how the distance map is normalized (the calculations). The formulas for normalization i have found do not calculate the same results as OpenCV normalize is giving me. This is not a question relating to the method not working, I need to include formulas in my thesis.

Comment: _'but doing the calculations do not yield the same results ...'_ Demonstrate how your alternate code does the calculations!

Comment: I use OpenCV normalize, this is not a coding question

Comment: _'this is not a coding question'_ OK, edited tags accordingly, retracted down & close vote ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula is:

out_val=(in_val-min_val)/(max_val-min_val);

- in_val - input matrix element value;
- out_val - output matrix element value;
- min_val - minimal element in input matrix;
- max_val - maximal element in input matrix.

Comment: This is exactly it, if I may ask - where did you get this?

Comment: I just know that NORM_MINMAX put all values to interval you set. This formula does it (for interval 0-1, shifts to 0 then scales to [0;1]).

Comment: Says so in documentation: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=normalize#normalize